# Maven in Eclipse. Error while generating Javadoc: Unable to find javadoc command: The environment variable JAVA_HOME is not correctly set

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, java-home

I have been searching for the fix for this for 3 days. I have read a lot of posts (including here) that describe how to fix it, but none seem to work. The class I am in was given starter code and we were required to import into eclipse as a new Maven project.  I import fine, made the changes (which have zero to do with this from what I can tell), compile it and I get the error above.

I am really new to this, but fill this has to be something simple.
We had a test scenario of creating a new maven project and then adding a class to it (setting the archetype and then Archetype Group Id, Artifact Id, and the version). That worked fine, but since this is an import, I am guessing that I need to go into a menu somewhere and change something.

Below is the full build log:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Chris/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.18.0.20210618-2246/jars/slf4j-simple-

1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/C:/Users/Chris/eclipse/java-2021-
```

09/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/5/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an
explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in
[jar:file:/C:/Users/Chris/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.18.0.20210618-2246/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/C:/Users/Chris/eclipse/java-2021-
09/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/5/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

```
 SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an e 
 explanation.
 SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] ----------------------< com.gamingroom:gameauth >-----------------------
 [INFO] Building GameAuth 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
 [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ gameauth ---
 [INFO] Deleting C:\Users\Chris\eclipse-workspace\gameauth\target
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ gameauth --- 
 [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
 [INFO] Copying 1 resource
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) @ gameauth ---
 [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
 [INFO] Compiling 11 source files to C:\Users\Chris\eclipse-workspace\gameauth\target\classes
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ gameauth ---
 [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
 [INFO] Copying 0 resource
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ gameauth ---
 [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ gameauth ---
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.0.2:jar (default-jar) @ gameauth ---
 [INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\Chris\eclipse-workspace\gameauth\target\gameauth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:2.4.1:shade (default) @ gameauth ---
 [INFO] Including io.dropwizard:dropwizard-auth:jar:1.0.0 in the shaded jar.
 [INFO] Including io.dropwizard:dropwizard-client:jar:1.0.0 in the shaded jar.
 [INFO] Including org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.23.1 in the shaded jar.
 [INFO] Including javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1 in the shaded jar.
 [INFO] Including org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.23.1 in the shaded jar.
 [INFO] Including javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2 in the shaded jar.
 [INFO] Including org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.23.1 in the shaded jar.
 [INFO] Including org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1 in the shaded jar.
 [INFO] Including org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.4.0-b34 in the shaded jar.
 [INFO] Including org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.4.0-b34 in the shaded jar.
 [INFO] Including org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.4.0-b34 in the shaded jar.
 [INFO] Including org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.4.0-b34 in the shaded jar.
 [INFO] Including org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.4.0-b34 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.4 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-httpclient:jar:3.1.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.glassfish.jersey.connectors:jersey-apache-connector:jar:2.23.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.dropwizard:dropwizard-core:jar:1.0.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.dropwizard:dropwizard-util:jar:1.0.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.7.6 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.guava:guava:jar:19.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.4 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.dropwizard:dropwizard-jackson:jar:1.0.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.7.6 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.7.6 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-guava:jar:2.7.6 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.7.6 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.7.6 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-afterburner:jar:2.7.6 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:jar:2.7.6 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.7 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.dropwizard:dropwizard-validation:jar:1.0.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.4.Final in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.2.1.Final in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.glassfish:javax.el:jar:3.0.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.dropwizard:dropwizard-configuration:jar:1.0.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.7.6 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.15 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.dropwizard:dropwizard-logging:jar:1.0.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-logback:jar:3.1.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.21 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.7 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.3.9.v20160517 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.dropwizard:dropwizard-metrics:jar:1.0.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.dropwizard:dropwizard-jersey:jar:1.0.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.23.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:jar:2.23.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-metainf-services:jar:2.23.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-bean-validation:jar:2.23.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jersey2:jar:3.1.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.7.6 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.7.6 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.7.6 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:jar:2.23.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.23.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.3.9.v20160517 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.3.9.v20160517 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.3.9.v20160517 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.3.9.v20160517 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:9.3.9.v20160517 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.dropwizard:dropwizard-servlets:jar:1.0.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-annotation:jar:3.1.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.dropwizard:dropwizard-jetty:jar:1.0.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jetty9:jar:3.1.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.3.9.v20160517 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.3.9.v20160517 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:jar:9.3.9.v20160517 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.3.9.v20160517 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.dropwizard:dropwizard-lifecycle:jar:1.0.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.1.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jvm:jar:3.1.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-servlets:jar:3.1.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-json:jar:3.1.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-healthchecks:jar:3.1.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.dropwizard:dropwizard-request-logging:jar:1.0.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including ch.qos.logback:logback-access:jar:1.1.7 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including net.sourceforge.argparse4j:argparse4j:jar:0.7.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.eclipse.jetty.toolchain.setuid:jetty-setuid-java:jar:1.0.3 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Replacing original artifact with shaded artifact.
[INFO] Replacing C:\Users\Chris\eclipse-workspace\gameauth\target\gameauth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar with C:\Users\Chris\eclipse-workspace\gameauth\target\gameauth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar
[INFO] Dependency-reduced POM written at: C:\Users\Chris\eclipse-workspace\gameauth\dependency-reduced-pom.xml
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:jar (attach-sources) > generate-sources @ gameauth >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:jar (attach-sources) < generate-sources @ gameauth <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:jar (attach-sources) @ gameauth ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\Chris\eclipse-workspace\gameauth\target\gameauth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-javadoc-plugin:3.0.0-M1:jar (attach-javadocs) @ gameauth ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  47.970 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-09-29T14:27:48-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.0.0-M1:jar (attach-javadocs) on project gameauth: MavenReportException: Error while generating Javadoc: Unable to find javadoc command: The environment variable JAVA_HOME is not correctly set. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Why are you using so old plugin versions See here a list of current versions: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Comment: This was created by the build, I am using the latest version of eclipse, honestly I have no idea if the plug ins are old or new or even where to change them.

Comment: Who has created that? `This was created by the build,`?

Comment: What i am saying is that we were given starter code. I imported that code into Eclipse as a Maven project.  I go to run as -> run configuration -> create a new one, I put in the name of the configuration, the workspace (${workspace_loc:/gameauth}) and hit run.  That is all I did.  The POM file has all of these in there (came from instructor that way).  I didn't add/remove or change anything but the FIX me items we were to fix.

Comment: The instructor should upgrade the template it's being used...

Comment: I can suggest that, but still that won't fix the issue, I don't think.  The other project where I created a maven project, it works fine, builds and works as expected.  Just something is blocking it .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.